# Why should we have a suffix after a number in this case?

Tags: c#

Given the following code, we can omit the `u` in the first line, the `l` in the second line, and the `ul` in the third line, and the values will be automatically converted to `uint`, `long` and `ulong`, respectively.

So why do we need the suffix (`u`, `l`, `ul`) in this case?

```
uint uintnum = 7u;
long longnum = 7l;
ulong ulongnum = 7ul;
```

Comment: For a good explanation, see http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457333/is-there-any-c-style-guide-that-talks-about-numeric-literal-suffixes) and [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/numeric-literal-suffixes.html) for about *why* you should use these.

Comment: please understand my question exactly,then give me a negative vote!!

Comment: @GT_mh yes,I got it,and would you please explain the reason of this action in casting conversion for me?

Comment: Why downvotes? Seems like a reasonable question. Wording isn't great, but English may not be this person's first language.

Comment: @Ryan,yes English is not my first language,so my Wording isn't great.thanks for your attention!

Comment: @Hava Darabi Sorry, I don't understand your second question. Could you elaborate on it?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to. Both the suffix and the explicit type declaration give the compiler information about how to store the variable. You **would** need the suffix if you were doing this instead:

```
var uintnum = 7u;
var longnum = 7l;
var ulongnum = 7ul;
```

Comment: ,I know that,I mean why some programmers may do such this?

Comment: If you see programs which use **both** an explicit type declaration **and** the suffix, it's just being redundant. In your examples above only one or the other is actually needed.

Comment: ,my teacher said that in other calculation,it may affect,would you please explain me that affect?

Comment: @HavaDarabi: If there is more going on to the right of the assignment operator then the suffix can be important.  In cases like that types are determined by the expression on the right before finally being assigned to the left, so that expression can have unexpected results if the types aren't explicitly given.